# Java statement before lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I had this code previously which worked

```
private Runnable persist(Data data) {
    data.setComparisonTime(NO_COMPARISON_PERFORMED);
    return () -> {
        ...
    };
}
```

Later I refactored the code as I'd missed this before.

```
private Runnable persist(Data data) { 
    return () -> {
        data.setComparisonTime(NO_COMPARISON_PERFORMED);
        ...
    };
}
```

What is the difference between these two statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matters for when the `data.setComparisonTime` is run. You have a function that returns a function; in the first case, the `setComparisonTime` will be run when the `persist` method is run. In the latter, it will not be run until the returned lambda is run.

Comment: The code was called via an optional method. ifPresentOrElse and seemed to work the same regardless?

Comment: @rob-DEV Probably by "mistake". If you did `Runnable r = persist(theData); theData.setComparisonTime(SOME_OTHER_VALUE); r.run();`, then I would expect the behavior of the first approach to change. That would (or should) have no effect on the second approach, because it sets the "comparison time" as part of the runnable implementation.